# Replace missing values by a reference value for each id in panel data

Tags: panel, stata

I have panel data:

```
    Id |       Wave| Localisation| Baseline
     1 |         1 |          AA |        1
     1 |         2 |          .  |        0
     1 |         3 |          .  |        0
     2 |         2 |          AB |        1
     2 |         3 |          .  |        0
     3 |         1 |          AB |        1
     3 |         3 |           . |        0
     4 |         2 |          AC |        1
     4 |         3 |           . |        0
```

Some variable values of one panel (`hhsize`, `localisation`, whatever) serves as a reference (these values are included in the baseline interview only).

By consequence, for each `id` we do not have all the information. For the `id==1` for instance, we have missing values in the column `Localisation` for not-baseline-interview (`baseline==0`).

I would like to spread the baseline values to each panel. That is, I want to replace missing values `.` in column `Localisation` by `Localisation` given in the baseline interview for each `id`.

In fact, the information `Localisation` remain the same across different waves. So it is useful to know the localization for each wave for one person.

Comment: It works, thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data pattern you present is the same for the entire dataset, then the following should work:

```
clear

input Id Wave str2 Localisation Baseline
1 1 AA 1
1 2  . 0
1 3  . 0
2 2 AB 1
2 3  . 0
3 1 AB 1
3 3  . 0
4 2 AC 1
4 3  . 0
end

bysort Id (Wave): replace Localisation = Localisation[1] if Localisation == "."

list, sepby(Id) abbreviate(15)

     +-------------------------------------+
     | Id   Wave   Localisation   Baseline |
     |-------------------------------------|
  1. |  1      1             AA          1 |
  2. |  1      2             AA          0 |
  3. |  1      3             AA          0 |
     |-------------------------------------|
  4. |  2      2             AB          1 |
  5. |  2      3             AB          0 |
     |-------------------------------------|
  6. |  3      1             AB          1 |
  7. |  3      3             AB          0 |
     |-------------------------------------|
  8. |  4      2             AC          1 |
  9. |  4      3             AC          0 |
     +-------------------------------------+
```